# Cohomology of $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb Z)$ with coefficients

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, arithmetic-groups

Let $K$ be a number field, which can be $\mathbb Q(\zeta)$ with $\zeta$ a root of unity if that helps, and let $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ act on $(K^\times)^n:=K^\times\times\cdots\times K^\times$ by «matrix multplication», so that $M\cdot (\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)=(\lambda_1^{m_{1,1}}\cdots\lambda_n^{m_{1,n}},\dots, \lambda_1^{m_{n,1}}\cdots\lambda_n^{m_{n,n}})$.

> Is the cohomology $H^*(\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}),(K^\times)^n)$ known, at least in degree $2$?

If $\mu$ is the group of roots of unity in $K$, then $\mu^n=\mu\times\cdots\times\mu$ is a $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$-submodule of $(K^\times)^n$, and one can also ask

> Is the cohomology $H^*(\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}),\mu^n)$ known, at least in degree $2$?

The two cohomologies are related by a long exact sequence, of course.

I am really interested in the case where $n=2$ which should be easier (?)...

Comment: Can't you exploit that SL_2(Z) is the amalgam of C_4 and C_6 along C_2 and apply the Mayer-Vietoris sequence?

Comment: That does work great if the coefficients have trivial action. You find, for example, that $H^2(\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Z),\mathbb Z)$ is $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$ and $0$ in odd degrees, so you can compute $H^2$ with values in finite cyclic groups with trivial action.

Comment: Whatever the answer is, I would not think it would have much to do with $K$. What is known about the cohomology in low degrees of $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$ with $\mathbb Z^n$ coefficients?

Comment: The Mayer-Vietoris sequence holds for all coefficients (cf. Brown VII.9) and the cohomology of cyclic groups is easy. So I would guess that you can get some information from MV.

Comment: Indeed, my coefficients are $\mathbb Z^n\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}(-)$ applied to $K^\times$ or~$\mu$. Taking this outside of the Ext will see the torsion, but the problem is probably with $\mathbb Z^n$.

Comment: Perhaps the following reference can be useful: "The cohomology of the braid group B_3 and of SL_2(Z) with coefficients in a geometric representation", 
Filippo Callegaro, Fred Cohen, Mario Salvetti.